# WebCore crash not able to find the root cause

Tags: javascript, swift, webkit, hostable-web-core

this is the main tread where the crash is happening, not able to reproduce in simulator, need some expert help on this.
we are making use of web view from authenticator to login and register it to the application, not sure this issue is from authenticator or from apple webview.
getting crashes from the user, and not able to reproduce it.

```
0
WebCore
<redacted> + 28
1
WebCore
<redacted> + 304
2
WebCore
<redacted> + 7500
3
WebCore
WebCore::SerializedScriptValue::deserialize(JSC::JSGlobalObject&, JSC::JSGlobalObject*, WebCore::SerializationErrorMode) + 56
4
WebCore
WebCore::SerializedScriptValue::deserialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue const**) + 72
5
WebKit
API::SerializedScriptValue::deserialize(WebCore::SerializedScriptValue&, OpaqueJSValue const**) + 76
6
WebKit
ScriptMessageHandlerDelegate::didPostMessage(WebKit::WebPageProxy&, WebKit::FrameInfoData&&, API::ContentWorld&, WebCore::SerializedScriptValue&) + 136
7
WebKit
WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::didPostMessage(WTF::ObjectIdentifier<WebKit::WebPageProxyIdentifierType>, WebKit::FrameInfoData&&, unsigned long long, WTF::Span<unsigned char const, 18446744073709551615ul> const&, WTF::CompletionHandler<void (WTF::Span<unsigned char const, 18446744073709551615ul> const&, WTF::String const&)>&&) + 732
8
WebKit
WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 2384
9
WebKit
IPC::MessageReceiverMap::dispatchMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 448
10
WebKit
WebKit::WebProcessProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 40
11
WebKit
IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Decoder> >) + 264
12
WebKit
IPC::Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages() + 608
13
JavaScriptCore
WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 200
14
JavaScriptCore
WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
15
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
16
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
17
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
18
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun + 828
19
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
20
GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal + 164
21
UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _run] + 1100
22
UIKitCore
UIApplicationMain + 364
23
App
AppDelegate.swift - Line 23
main + 23
24
(Missing)
```

Comment: its happening only in ios 15 +